# In the exapnsion of $(1+x+x^3+x^4)^{10}$, find the coefficient of $x^4$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In the exapnsion of $(1+x+x^3+x^4)^{10}$, find the coefficient of $x^4$.

What's the strategy to approach such problems.  Writing expansion seems tedious here.

Comment: Think of every possible way you could multiply exactly ten things together chosen with replacement from the set $\{1, x, x^3, x^4\}$ and get a result of $x^4$. Count them, and that will be your coefficient. The main thing is that you either have to build it up from $x^3\cdot x$ or $x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x$, or just an $x^4$ (and a bunch of $1$s, in each case), and you just have to count how many ways you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

$$=(1+x^3)^{10}(1+x)^{10}$$

So, required coefficient of $x^4$ will be $$\binom{10}0\binom{10}4+\binom{10}1\binom{10}1$$

Comment: $$+\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}$$

Comment: I don't think so.  $10 \choose 4$ is the number of ways to form it from $4$ copies of $x$. You can also pick an $x^4$ in $10$ ways.  You can also pick an $x$ in $10$ ways followed by an $x^3$ in $9$ ways.

Comment: @Lutzl, Thanks for the observation

Comment: @RossMillikan in $(1+10x^3+...)(1+10x+\binom{10}2x^2+\binom{10}3x^3+\binom{10}4x^4+...)$ you obtain the 4th power in two ways, as $1\cdot x^4$ and as $x^3\cdot x$.

Comment: So the ${10 \choose 1}^2$ matches the sum of my last two items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [multinomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$
(a+b+c+d)^{10}=\sum_{p+q+r+s=10}\binom{10}{p\ q\ r\ s}a^pb^qc^rd^s
$$
where
$$
\binom{10}{p\ q\ r\ s}=\frac{10!}{p!q!r!s!}
$$
With $a=1$, $b=x$, $c=x^3$, $d=x^4$, we have
$$
a^pb^qc^rd^s=x^{q+3r+4s}
$$
We get $q+3r+4s=4$ if and only if $q=4$, $r=0$, $s=0$ or $q=1$, $r=1$, $s=0$ or $q=0$, $r=0$, $s=1$. Thus the coefficient is
$$
\binom{10}{6\ 4\ 0\ 0}+\binom{10}{8\ 1\ 1\ 0}+\binom{10}{9\ 0\ 0\ 1}
=\frac{10!}{6!4!}+\frac{10!}{8!1!1!}+\frac{10!}{9!1!}=210+90+10=310
$$

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Jack Crawford's comment above, there are three possible ways to get $x^4$:
$$\underbrace{1\times1\times\cdots\times 1}_{9}\times x^4\\
\underbrace{1\times1\times\cdots\times 1}_{8}\times x\times x^3\\
\underbrace{1\times1\times\cdots\times 1}_{6}\times x\times x\times x \times x$$
The first is the combination: ${10\choose 1}=10$.

The second is the permutation: $P(10,2)=\frac{10!}{8!}=90$.

The third is again combination: ${10\choose 4}=210$.

Hence: $10+90+210=310$.